# git diff and code review in common branch

Tags: git, version-control

Im using git.
Say we have a common branch that multiple people are working on.
A rather large change is being done, say it has 20 commits and a considerable amount of lines changed.
Now say the "change" / "feature" / "fix" being done is identified with a commit-message.
So that in the git-log, the commits look like:

```
TASK-X: Add foo.
TASK-Y: Added rofl.
TASK-X: Added bar.
TASK-X: Added baz.
```

Now, imagine this at a much larger scale. Imagine huge amounts of commits being done in between each other. And someone now tells me "Do a code review on TASK X".

I can easily find all the relevant commits - but say a lot of the commits contain stuff like "Added debug statements", "Removed debug statements", "Fixed a bug in my code" etc.

Going through commit by commit would be very tiresome, as I might notice errors that have been fixed in a later (upcomming)commit, and I also lack the context of the commits in their entirety.

Is there a way of showing the combined/consolidated commits for task X, but **not** include all other non-relevant commits done in between?

PS: I know that a better way is doing feature branches, and forcing people to cleanup their own mess before merging, but I can't do anything about that.

Comment: What is your central repository system? gerrit? stash? github? gitlab? bitbucket etc?

Comment: EDIT: Misread your question. The central repo I have no clue about. Not github, bitbucket or such: An internal thing, most likely.

Comment: Central repo!! where do you push your code to? to which system?

Comment: Check comment above. Seems I didnt edit my comment in time :) I assume its just a bare central git repo on an internal custom server/host.
git init --bare --shared foo.git

Comment: Ok, no central repo simply ssh clone

Comment: If you mean "central repo" as an external service with accompanying websites and tools, such as github, bitbucket etc then no, we're not using that.
But we _do_ use a centralized workflow, using a common server as the central repo where everyone push to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a (temporary) review branch based on the commit just before the first commit for TASK X

```
git branch review-TASK_X <first commit for TASK X>^
```

Then cherry-pick all commits for TASK X one by one

```
git cherry-pick <first commit for TASK X>
git cherry-pick <second commit for TASK X>
....
git cherry-pick <last commit for TASK X>
```

Then simply diff this branch between its HEAD and its branch point

```
git diff <first commit for TASK X>^
```